# biblatex: splitting bibliography entry which are connected by name as "package"

Tags: latex, biblatex

I'm currently struggeling with my BibLaTeX file. I wanna separate the bibtex entries which are connected by the last name of the author (as you can see with the first and second entry). Also i wanna turn the (Hrsg.) Tag like the rest of the author information in bold.

[image]

below you can find a mre where the magic happens.

regards and stay healthy!

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\newif\ifde
\newif\ifen
\newcommand{\langde}[1]{%
   \ifde\selectlanguage{ngerman}#1\fi}
\newcommand{\langen}[1]{%
   \ifen\selectlanguage{english}#1\fi}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\langde{\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}}
\langen{\usepackage[babel,english=british]{csquotes}}
\usepackage{footnote}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ext-authoryear,
maxcitenames=3, % mindestens 3 Namen ausgeben bevor et. al. kommt
maxbibnames=999,
mergedate=false,
date=iso,
seconds=true, %werden nicht verwendet, so werden aber Warnungen unterdrückt.
urldate=iso,
innamebeforetitle,
dashed=false,
autocite=footnote,
doi=false,
useprefix=true, % 'von' im Namen beachten (beim Anzeigen)
mincrossrefs = 1
]{biblatex}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xpatch}

\setlength\bibhang{1cm}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book}{
    \clearfield{issn}%
    \clearfield{doi}%
    \clearfield{isbn}%
    \clearfield{url}
    \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
\ifentrytype{collection}{
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{isbn}%
  \clearfield{url}
  \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
\ifentrytype{incollection}{
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{isbn}%
  \clearfield{url}
  \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
\ifentrytype{article}{
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{isbn}%
  \clearfield{url}
  \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
\ifentrytype{inproceedings}{
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{isbn}%
  \clearfield{url}
  \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}%Kein Punkt am ende des Literaturverzeichnisses

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{titleyeardelim}{\newunitpunct}
%Namen kursiv schreiben
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\mkbibemph}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}{\mkbibemph}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}{\mkbibemph}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}{\mkbibemph}


\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}  %Nach Namen sortieren


\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{translatortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{innametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\usebibmacro{organization+location+date}\newunit\newblock}
  {}
  {}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urltime}{\addspace #1\addspace \langde{Uhr}\langen{MEZ}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%urltime zu urldate hinzufügen
  [\langde{Zugriff}\langen{Access}\addcolon\addspace
  #1\printfield{urltime}]
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{url}{<\url{#1}>}
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \ifentrytype{online}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \iffieldundef{year}
       {\printtext[date]{\langde{keine Datumsangabe}\langen{no Date} }}
       {\usebibmacro{date}}}%
    {}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{urldate}
  }
\DeclareExtradate{
  \scope{
    \field{labelyear}
    \field{year}
    }
    \scope{
      \field{usera}
     }
}
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \printfield{usera}%
    \setunit{\printdelim{titleyeardelim}}%
    \ifentrytype{online}
       {\setunit*{\addspace\addcomma\addspace}%
         \iffieldundef{year}
           {\bibstring{nodate}}
       {\printlabeldateextra}}%
       {\printlabeldateextra}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
    \ifentrytype{online}
       {\setunit*{\addspace\addcomma\addspace}%
         \iffieldundef{year}
           {\bibstring{nodate}}
       {\printlabeldateextra}}%
       {\printlabeldateextra}}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  nodate    = {{}o.\adddot\addspace J\adddot},
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  nodate    = {{}n.\adddot\addspace d\adddot},
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[notfield=translator, final]
      \step[notfield=editor, final]
      \step[fieldset=author, fieldvalue={{{\langde{o\noexpand\adddot\addspace V\noexpand\adddot}\langen{Anon}}}}]
    }
    \map{
      \pernottype{online}
      \step[fieldset=location, fieldvalue={\langde{o\noexpand\adddot\addspace O\noexpand\adddot}\langen{s\noexpand\adddot I\noexpand\adddot}}]
    }
  }
}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonametitledelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}%
     \printfield{usera}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{titleyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

    \renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\jourvoldelim}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\jourserdelim}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\servoldelim}}%
  \iffieldundef{volume}
    {}
    {\printfield{volume}}
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
  {}
  {
  (\thefield{year}) %Ansonsten wird wenn kein Volume angegeben ist ein Komma vorangestellt
  }
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace Nr\adddot\addspace}
  \printfield{number}
  \iffieldundef{eid}
  {}
  {\printfield{eid}}
}


\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \setunit{\postnotedelim}%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {} %{\printtext{\langde{o.S\adddot}\langen{no page number}}}
    {\printfield{postnote}}}

\setlength{\bibinitsep}{0.75cm}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nonameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
      {\toggletrue{abx@bool@giveninits}
        \printnames[family-given]{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
      \printfield{usera}%
      \setunit{\printdelim{titleyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
   {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}



\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@article{Raab2008,
  author  = {Raab, Markus and Philippen, Philipp B.},
  title   = {Auf der suche nach einfachheit in Vorhersagemodellen im Sport},
  journal = {Sportwissenschaft},
  year    = {2008},
  month   = {Dec},
  day     = {01},
  volume  = {38},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {464-471},
  issn    = {1868-1069},
  doi     = {10.1007/BF03217048},
  url     = {https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03217048}
}

@article{Reep1971,
  doi       = {10.2307/2343657},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.2307/2343657},
  year      = {1971},
  publisher = {{JSTOR}},
  volume    = {134},
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {623},
  author    = {C. Reep and R. Pollard and B. Benjamin},
  title     = {Skill and Chance in Ball Games},
  journal   = {Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series A (General)}
}

@book{ddos,
  doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-77525-8},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-77525-8},
  year = {2019},
  publisher = {Springer International Publishing},
  editor = {Sherif Sakr and Albert Y. Zomaya},
  title = {Encyclopedia of Big Data Technologies}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\footcite{Reep1971}, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\printbibliography{}

\end{document}
```

my excpeted result is what i want to achieve should look like this:

[image]

PS: if you have any tips for a better title for this problem (for everyone who's gonna face this problem) feel free to edit! :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "split my bibtex entries which are connected by the last name of the author."?

Comment: i wanna separate the entries by a newline. between the first and second entry there ist no new line. i think ist has to do with the letter ```R``` and so they are connected

Comment: The space between the items is controlled by `\bibitemsep`, I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to make the author names bold from [biblatex: customizing bibliography entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575574/biblatex-customizing-bibliography-entry) - the same technique can be used for the `editorstrg`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\newif\ifde
\newif\ifen
\newcommand{\langde}[1]{%
   \ifde\selectlanguage{ngerman}#1\fi}
\newcommand{\langen}[1]{%
   \ifen\selectlanguage{english}#1\fi}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\langde{\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}}
\langen{\usepackage[babel,english=british]{csquotes}}
\usepackage{footnote}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ext-authoryear,
maxcitenames=3, % mindestens 3 Namen ausgeben bevor et. al. kommt
maxbibnames=999,
mergedate=false,
date=iso,
seconds=true, %werden nicht verwendet, so werden aber Warnungen unterdrückt.
urldate=iso,
innamebeforetitle,
dashed=false,
autocite=footnote,
doi=false,
useprefix=true, % 'von' im Namen beachten (beim Anzeigen)
mincrossrefs = 1
]{biblatex}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xpatch}

\setlength\bibhang{1cm}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book}{
    \clearfield{issn}%
    \clearfield{doi}%
    \clearfield{isbn}%
    \clearfield{url}
    \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
\ifentrytype{collection}{
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{isbn}%
  \clearfield{url}
  \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
\ifentrytype{incollection}{
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{isbn}%
  \clearfield{url}
  \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
\ifentrytype{article}{
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{isbn}%
  \clearfield{url}
  \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
\ifentrytype{inproceedings}{
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{isbn}%
  \clearfield{url}
  \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}%Kein Punkt am ende des Literaturverzeichnisses

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{titleyeardelim}{\newunitpunct}
%Namen kursiv schreiben
%\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\mkbibbold}
%\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}{\mkbibbold}
%\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}{\mkbibbold}
%\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}{\mkbibbold}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{extradate}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}  %Nach Namen sortieren


\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{translatortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{innametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\usebibmacro{organization+location+date}\newunit\newblock}
  {}
  {}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urltime}{\addspace #1\addspace \langde{Uhr}\langen{MEZ}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%urltime zu urldate hinzufügen
  [\langde{Zugriff}\langen{Access}\addcolon\addspace
  #1\printfield{urltime}]
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{url}{<\url{#1}>}
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \ifentrytype{online}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \iffieldundef{year}
       {\printtext[date]{\langde{keine Datumsangabe}\langen{no Date} }}
       {\usebibmacro{date}}}%
    {}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{urldate}
  }
\DeclareExtradate{
  \scope{
    \field{labelyear}
    \field{year}
    }
    \scope{
      \field{usera}
     }
}
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \printfield{usera}%
    \setunit{\printdelim{titleyeardelim}}%
    \ifentrytype{online}
       {\setunit*{\addspace\addcomma\addspace}%
         \iffieldundef{year}
           {\bibstring{nodate}}
       {\printlabeldateextra}}%
       {\printlabeldateextra}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
    \ifentrytype{online}
       {\setunit*{\addspace\addcomma\addspace}%
         \iffieldundef{year}
           {\bibstring{nodate}}
       {\printlabeldateextra}}%
       {\printlabeldateextra}}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  nodate    = {{}o.\adddot\addspace J\adddot},
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  nodate    = {{}n.\adddot\addspace d\adddot},
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[notfield=translator, final]
      \step[notfield=editor, final]
      \step[fieldset=author, fieldvalue={{{\langde{o\noexpand\adddot\addspace V\noexpand\adddot}\langen{Anon}}}}]
    }
    \map{
      \pernottype{online}
      \step[fieldset=location, fieldvalue={\langde{o\noexpand\adddot\addspace O\noexpand\adddot}\langen{s\noexpand\adddot I\noexpand\adddot}}]
    }
  }
}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonametitledelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}%
     \printfield{usera}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{titleyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

    \renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\jourvoldelim}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\jourserdelim}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\servoldelim}}%
  \iffieldundef{volume}
    {}
    {\printfield{volume}}
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
  {}
  {
  (\thefield{year}) %Ansonsten wird wenn kein Volume angegeben ist ein Komma vorangestellt
  }
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace Nr\adddot\addspace}
  \printfield{number}
  \iffieldundef{eid}
  {}
  {\printfield{eid}}
}


\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \setunit{\postnotedelim}%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {} %{\printtext{\langde{o.S\adddot}\langen{no page number}}}
    {\printfield{postnote}}}

%\setlength{\bibinitsep}{0.75cm}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nonameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
      {\toggletrue{abx@bool@giveninits}
        \printnames[family-given]{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
      \printfield{usera}%
      \setunit{\printdelim{titleyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
   {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Raab2008,
  author  = {Raab, Markus and Philippen, Philipp B.},
  title   = {Auf der Suche nach Einfachheit in Vorhersagemodellen im Sport},
  journal = {Sportwissenschaft},
  year    = {2008},
  month   = {Dec},
  day     = {01},
  volume  = {38},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {464-471},
  issn    = {1868-1069},
  doi     = {10.1007/BF03217048},
  url     = {https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03217048}
}

@article{Reep1971,
  doi       = {10.2307/2343657},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.2307/2343657},
  year      = {1971},
  publisher = {{JSTOR}},
  volume    = {134},
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {623},
  author    = {C. Reep and R. Pollard and B. Benjamin},
  title     = {Skill and Chance in Ball Games},
  journal   = {Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series A (General)}
}

@book{ddos,
  doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-77525-8},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-77525-8},
  year = {2019},
  publisher = {Springer International Publishing},
  editor = {Sherif Sakr and Albert Y. Zomaya},
  title = {Encyclopedia of Big Data Technologies}
}
\end{filecontents}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

  \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \mkbibbold{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{\printlabeldateextra}}}}%
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family-bold}
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given/given-family-bold}{%
  \mkbibbold{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartgiven}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartprefix}}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
  
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \mkbibbold{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography{}

\end{document}
```

[image]